# iPhone What should I do to keep the angle as I set and change the size?

Tags: iphone, ios, rotation, scale

I’m adjusting a view’s scale and rotation using  two UISliders.

When I change the rotation of view and then change it's scale, the rotation returns to 0 and the scale is also initialized.

What should I do to keep the rotation constant as I set and change the scale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should concat the transformations like this: `CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleX, scaleY), CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle));`